# Angular 6 : Http upgrade

Tags: angular, angular6

i am trying to send a http request and as per the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fh2GyYQcuxU) i added HttpClientModule in app.module.ts,but facing below error in console of browser.

> Unexpected module 'HttpClientModule' declared by the module
>   'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

please help.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LandingpageComponent } from './landingpage/landingpage.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LandingpageComponent,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Did any of the answers help resolve your issue? If so mark the answer that help you the most. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Move the module out of `declarations` and into `imports` to resolve this error. You import modules, not declare them.

```
imports:[BrowserModule, HttpClientModule]
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 2):

`declarations` array is only for Pipes, Directives, and Components, you need to add the module in `imports` array

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LandingpageComponent } from './landingpage/landingpage.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LandingpageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```